# How do you override the automatically generated fieldnames in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a (pre-existing) table witha column 'foo'.  I want the model to have a property 'bar' which maps to foo.

I already use

```
class Meta:
    db_table = u'actual_table_name'
```

to remap classes/tables from the default table name.  Is there a similar way to do this for properties/fields?

Thanks,

Chris.

P.S. This seems like a very simple question, I'm probably just blind to that section of the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Field.db_column](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#db-column).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right - don't know how I didn't come across the http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/ field manual page before.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give this a try: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='foo')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'actual_table_name'
```